# Insufficient developer role during Instagram Basic Display app review

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We are trying to get our Instagram Basic Display app reviewed. But we keep being rejected because the reviewer gets an Error 400: "insufficient developer role" (of course, we do not get this error with our test users).

See the attached screenshot that was provided by the reviewer.

[image]

I would assume that the reviewers would have a special test account that does not need to be added to the test users of our app?

And also we cannot put the app in Live mode because it was not approved during the review process.

What are we doing wrong here?

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue finally? We are currently facing the same issue

Comment: @TerrelLewis see my answer - good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody will tell you but you need to:

1. create a **Facebook** test user
2. create an **Instagram** account with that FB test user
3. give the credentials (email/address) of the **Facebook** test user to the reviewer in the Instagram Basic Display submission